# RMarkdown with PPT: Not able to render ppt in rstudio when using reference_doc

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, pandoc

I am trying to use the below yaml header when building a RMarkdown to generate a powerpoint on my Mac using Rstudio —

```
---
title: "Traffic"
output: 
  powerpoint_presentation:
    reference_doc: template.pptx
---
```

However, when I knit this in Rstudio, I get below error —

output file: powerpoint_presentation_example.knit.md

pandoc: template.pptx: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
Execution halted.

Please Note : I was able to knit and generate a ppt just fine without using the reference_doc: template.pptx.